# qmake issue while installing capybara-webkit gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm trying to install **capybara-webkit** gem and it's throwing the following error.

`qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory`

What is the solution to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this to resolve above problem

```
apt-get install qt-sdk
```

After installing qt-sdk install capybara-webkit gem.